# HTML to Excel + changing pages loop

Tags: html, excel, vba, loops, getelementbyid

The error says `Object variable or With block variable are not set`. But when I'm trying to define doc as a document or word document it just doesn't allow to do that. Thanks in advance!!!

```
Sub HTMLtoExcel()
 Dim doc As Object
 Dim i As String
 i = 1
 Do While i <= 1783
 Set doc.getElementById("Pages").Value = CStr(i)
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http:/xxx.yyy" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = _
    "its_details_value_node.html?nsc=true&listId=www_s201_b9233&tsId=BBK01.ED0439"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    i = i + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know if I can answer your question but I have a couple of thoughts. Shouldn't "i" be "Dim"'d as a "Long" or "Double". Also, don't you have to "Dim" "CStr" as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc` is `Nothing`. The line is breaking because you're essentially doing `Set Nothing.getElementById("Pages").Value = CStr(i)`

> But when I'm trying to define doc as a document or word document

Well you need to clarify what's happening because this is not syntax that you can use with a `Word Document` object, but rather an webpage `.Document`.  Since you're using `QueryTables`, I assume the latter:

In order to resolve this, you need to first create an instance of a web browser, and set the `doc` by that, like:

```
Dim ie as Object

Set ie = CreateObject("Internet.Explorer")

ie.Navigate "http://google.com"  'Modify as needed

Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4 And Not ie.Busy
    DoEvents
    'It is better to use the WinAPI sleep function
    ' there are several examples of implementing this here on SO
Loop

Set doc = ie.Document
```

With that in mind, this line does not make any sense:

```
Set doc.getElementById("Pages").Value = CStr(i)
```

For starters, the `.Value` is not an object, so you can't `Set` it.  Also, the `getElementByID` *returns* an object. Perhaps you want:

```
doc.getElementById("Pages").Value = Cstr(i)
```

Now you have a loop that is executing 1783 times, but it will not work as you expect, because you are not changing any parameters in the `QueryString`, so if it does work 1783 times, it is just going to pull in the *same* data every time.  If you have trouble with that you should **ask that as a separate/new question**.

You will also need to  `Dim i as Integer` or `Long`, not as String in this context, otherwise this line is likely to raise a mismatch error: `i = i + 1`.